# Is it a bug in clang that defines a member of a namespace without using nested-name-specifier

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
namespace A{
    namespace B{
        template<typename T>
        struct Test{
        };
    }
    using namespace B;
    template<>
    struct Test<int>{};  //#1
}

int main(){

}
```

Consider the above code, `GCC` complains such code is ill-formed and `Clang` consider such code is well-formed. The outcome is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Kzoj6s). At `#1`, it's an explicit specialization declaration for class template `Test`. According to this rule:
[temp.expl.spec#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#2)

> An explicit specialization may be declared in any scope in which the **corresponding primary template may be defined**.

The primary template `Test` can be defined outside namespace `B`, as long as it obeys the following rule:
[namespace.memdef#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.memdef#2)

> Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that namespace **by explicit qualification ([namespace.qual]) of the name being defined**, provided that the entity being defined was already declared in the namespace and the definition **appears after the point of declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration's namespace**.

That is we may define the primary template `Test` like this:

```cpp
namespace A{
    namespace B{
        template<typename T>
        struct Test;
    }
    template<typename T>
    struct B::Test{  // Test is explicit qualified by B
    }; 
}
```

So, we're permitted to define explicit specialization at such point. However It's unclear that It is necessary to declare such explicit specialization by using qualified-id? However an additional rule is here:
[temp.expl.spec#8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#8)

> A template explicit specialization is **in the scope of the namespace in which the template was defined**.

So `Clang` is wrong?  How to interpret such case.

Comment: Short answer is that it is a bug. This is no different then defining a non-template function. Also consider the case of there being a `template struct Test` declared in `namespace A` before `namespace B` - which `struct Test` would you be defining?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  Not necessarily. The standard only says the explicit specialization may be declared in the scope where the primary template may declared. It didn't say the declarator-id of explicit specialization must be a `qualified-id` which contain `nested-name-specifier` that named enclosing namespace. So, I think it's unclear in the standard. Maybe `Clang` is right.

Comment: I read the code, thought "sure, it's a bug" but then, I finally noticed `using namespace B;`. I wouldn't be surprised at all if it was intended behavior. I, as a user of a programming language, would expect this to work like that. Sure, that's C++, not all things are as-human-would-intuively-expect, but still..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Maybe `Clang` is right, rather `GCC` is wrong. According to the first and the second quote.

Comment: @JackX " explicit qualification ([namespace.qual])" **does** mean the name must be qualified.

Comment: @Oliv what it says is **definition for the member of a namespace**. However `explicit specialization a template does not introduce a name `, So, that's not the definition for `Test` itself. Moreover, `Test<T>` is not the name of the member. It's just a `template-id`

Comment: @JackX `Test` is a member of namespace `B`.  The member name is `Test`.  `template <class T> struct test {...}` is not an explicit specialization, this is a definition. There is not specialization here. A definition is not a specialization! To recap 1) *members of a named namespace* => OK for `Test`: it is a member of named namespace `B`. *can also be **defined** by explicit qualification of the name being defined* => `B::Test` is the name `Test` explicitly qualified by `B::` it names member `Test` of namespace `B` and `template <class T> struct B::Test {` is a definition of the primary templa

Comment: @Oliv I said  the first code.  `Test` is a member of `B` and `A` is the enclosing namespace of `B`, where the definition of `Test` may be defined in `A`, so the explicit specialization could be defined here.  `Test<int>` is not the name of that template and it's not the definition for template `Test`. It's a explicit specialization.  hence `Clang` is right.

Comment: @jackX Oh that. I thin that the last paragraph you site is just to say that in some part of the declaration and in the definition of the specialization, names are looked up from namespace B not A. A specialization is also a member of the namespace of the primary template. I think this is clearer in the C++20 standard. Imagine that you fall on such a specialization in real code as the one clang accept. How could you know that names in the definition of the specialization does not refer to tje apparently enclosing namespace?

Comment: @Oliv You're right about the last paragraph. However you're wrong about `A specialization is also a member of the namespace of the primary template`, see [namespace.memdef#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.memdef#1), whose class-head-name or enum-head-name is an **identifier**

Comment: @jackX I am not sure it is that clear, I recurrently ask for that I never got an answer... Let's ask Davis Herring

Comment: @Oliv yup. for class template, the `declarator-id` which is a `template-id` is not the member of the namespace which enclosing the primary class template, It's clear in the link I cited in the above comment. But, I'm not sure whether the explicit specialization for function template is or not? Because the standards says `whose declarator-id is an unqualified-id`, it may be `template-id`.

Comment: @Oliv what Davis Herring have answered you seems to conform to the last quote in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the existing wording is more than a little unclear.  I won’t try to fathom its meaning as written, if it has one, further than you already have; I consider it all bad enough to need a [complete rewrite](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r5.html).

The **intent**, however, is that this code is well-formed (as Clang says); because the explicit specialization (of a class template) must contain `Test<`, which might be part of a *nested-name-specifier* (`template<> struct Test<int>::Nested<float> {};`), `Test` is subject to a normal name lookup that follows the *using-directive* (among many other things).  Note that this differs from [class.pre]/3 which forbids using a *nested-name-specifier* to redeclare a class brought in via a *using-declaration*.  (The rules for explicit specializations and instantiations of function templates are a bit more complicated because the template argument list is optional.)

Within a few weeks, there will be a public update of my linked paper that adjusts the rules for redeclarations along these lines (in [class.pre] in this case).

Comment: I wait and see. However the current quotes implies that `Clang` is right. That is, the explicit specialization could be defined in a namespace where its primary template could defined and at that point, as long as the template name could be found.

Comment: @DavisHerring I have a question since a long time that makes me unable to interpret some paragraph of the standard: Should specialization (instantiated or declared) be interpreted as members of the primary template namespace when one read the standard?

Comment: @Oliv: They belong to it for the purposes of ADL, but they’re never found by name lookup so in most respects it doesn’t matter.

Comment: @DavisHerring It seems to the quote in [namespace.memdef#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.memdef#1) clarifies whether a declaration is the member of the enclosing namespace or not, It's clear about `class/class template`, as long as the `class-head-name` is a `template-id`, it's not the member of the enclosing namespace. However it's unclear about explicit specialization for function template, whose `declarator-id` could be an `unqualified-id`, according to what the standard says, It sounds like specialization for function template is the member of the enclosing namespace

Comment: @DavisHerring So you could answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105174/when-is-there-an-ub-because-the-best-overload-match-was-not-found-by-adl-at-the?noredirect=1#comment111684658_63105174

Comment: @DavisHerring After reading the current draft(after P1787) carefully. I still have a doubt about the example in [class#pre-example-1]. I also post the issue to [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/4592#issuecomment-826057602). It seems there's no convinced rule in the current draft that states why the explicit specialization definition for `A<void>` in that example is an error.